# Looping JSON document, loading string into array then manipulating the document

Tags: php, arrays, string

I am looping through a json response and want to load parts of the document into an array. 
Currently I'm only able to echo out the parsed strings.

```
foreach($data['movies'] as $item) {
        echo $item['release_dates']['theater'];
}
```

How would I go about changing this so it loads the result into an array?

The parsed strings I want to put into the array are dates

Furthermore I have an example script working that finds the difference between 2 dates and loops an image for the difference. Could I manipulate this so instead of finding the difference between the variables, it finds the difference between the array objects constructed in the previous array loop?

```
$d1 = strtotime('2012-04-04');
$d2 = strtotime('2012-03-31');

$interval=($d1-$d2)/(3600*24);
for ($i = 0; $i <= $interval; $i++) 
{ 
  echo '<img src="test.jpg">';
}
```

Comment: Would `(array)json_decode($array)` and `json_decode($array)` help? Those functions are built into PHP5+

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this first part correctly, then this might be what you're asking for?

```
$dataArray = array();
foreach($data['movies'] as $item) {
    $dataArray[] = $item['release_dates'];
}
```